# How to change button colour on click?

Tags: css, angular

I want to change my button colour on click using angular and css as I am very new to it.

.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'title';
}
```

.html

```
 <mat-sidenav color="primary" #sidenav fxLayout="column" mode="over"  opened="false"           fxHide.gt-sm="true">
    <div fxLayout="column">
      
        <button mat-button style="text-align:left" routerLink="butn1" >Attend</button>
        <button mat-button style="text-align:left" routerLink="butn2" >Host</button>
       
        <button mat-button style="text-align:left" routerLink="contact" >Contact</button>
        <button mat-button style="text-align:left" routerLink="login" >Login</button>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in the html button tag
‘<button [class.mycolorclass]=’hasClicked’ (click)=’hasClicked=true’
The logic in the click directive can be moved into a method in the typescript class if you prefer that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with angular, but CSS `:active` should manage to do this:

```css
button {
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}

button:active {
  color: red;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

on button click set variable true/false as per your requirement

```
buttonClicked=false;

onButtonClick(){
this.buttonClicked=true;
}
```

and give condition in HTML like this

```
 <button mat-button
 [ngClass]="buttonClicked? 'myClassHighlighted' : 'none'" 
 style="text-align:left" routerLink="attend" >Attend</button>
```

and in css add classes like

```
.myClassHighlighted{
//your styles here
}

.none{
//your styles here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'title';
    buttons = [
        { title: 'Attend', link: 'butn1', active: false },
        { title: 'Host', link: 'butn2', active: false },
        { title: 'Contact', link: 'contact', active: false },
        { title: 'Login', link: 'login', active: false },
    ]

    toggleColor(button) {
        button.active = !button.active;
    }
}
```

.html

```
<mat-sidenav color="primary" #sidenav fxLayout="column" mode="over"  opened="false"           fxHide.gt-sm="true">
    <div fxLayout="column">
        <button
            mat-button
            *ngFor="let button of buttons"
            [color]="button.active ? 'accent' : 'primary'"
            style="text-align:left"
            [routerLink]="button.link"
            (click)="toggleColor(button)">
            {{ button.title }}
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: when i cilck on one button , all other buttons colour are also changeing , how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Use ngClass in your buttons to give 'em conditional classes based on a flag which is set true only when you click on that button so I guess you will need ngClick as well, well I don't know about the version of Angular that you are using right now cuz you didn't mention that but now you know you will need ngClass and ngClick for sure and your code might look like sth like this:

```
 <button mat-button style="text-align:left" [ngClass]="{'button--clicked': clicked}" routerLink="attend" (click)="clicked=!clicked" >Attend</button>
```

Comment: I am using angular 9 , can you plese guide me with the help of this code.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add css class for button based on click css value change